# asp.net drop down list duplicated itself when post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

#### It is a very weird problem

when I change the value of the drop down list, a new drop down list is show. I am so confused,

To know what I am talking about, please check these images.

#### edit

code for bind

```
    CallerId = Request["CallerID"];
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CallerId)) return;
    var results = ZumaDa.GetCustomerInformation(CallerId);
    rowCount = results.Rows.Count;
    CallerId = rowCount > 0 ? results.Rows[0][4].ToString() : CallerId;
    if (rowCount > 1)
    {
        ListView1.Enabled = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = results;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.Enabled = false;
        ListView1.DataSource = results;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

That code is in page load and NOT on !ispostback

Comment: both images looks same...

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi no no :) the second one has the additional droop down list at the top, please look. So weird

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi help please

Comment: @jadarnel27 is it always `Itesm[0]` or I need to use another index?

Comment: @jadarnel27 what did you mean by `adding the listView markup` pelase? sorry i am new to asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you updated your question with the ListView markup, and your Page_Load code, it appears the problem of the duplicated DropDownList goes away after you wrap your databinding code in an `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` block.

One problem in your code is that, in your SelectedIndexChanged event, you're searching the ListView for your DropDownList and TextBox.  You need to search the ListViewItem control where the SelectedIndexChanged event occurred.

To do that, you can first get the DropDownList from the "sender" parameter. Then you should find the "NamingContainer" control of the DropDownList, and search that.  Like this:

```
var dropDown = (DropDownList)sender;
var visitID = (TextBox)dropDown.NamingContainer.FindControl("visitID");
```

That second line of code might need to have an additional ".NamingContainer" depending on your markup.

Comment: First, let us try to solve the duplicated problem, you said that you need more code, I will edit my question to give you the code.

Comment: That's a good idea!  I'll watch for your edit, @MarcoDinatsoli.

Comment: help please, i need help

Comment: no it is empty, but look, i tried to put the update panel inside the td, and the second select is not shown, but the text also in the input is not shown, so there are 2 posibilities. the first one, is the function of the select is not firing, the second one is the code of writing to the input text is not correct, what do you suggest please?

Comment: is there any way to know if the function is firing when I change the select value please? i cann't make a break point because i don't have the databsea, and thus, every time i change my code, i deploy the website on the server. and i test the results.

Comment: there is no `NamiingContainer` . the vs tells me that the `NamimingContainer` is not exists

Comment: bty now my code is as you suggest in the comment `
            var dropDown = (DropDownList)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("callDispositionSelector");
            
            var visitID = (TextBox)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("visitID");`

Comment: Now when i change the value of the select, the page is post back but the select returns to its default value and the text is empty, it seems that the update padnel is not working.

Comment: yes, the page is post back but the update panel is not working anymore, i told you that i moved the update panel to inside the td in order to avoid that duplicated select, but in this case the select is always keep in the default value and i can see the page is posting back

Comment: Remove `runat="server"` from the `tr` and `td` elements around the ListView.  And please stop asking me to help you.  I'm already trying to help you.  You don't need to keep saying that.

Comment: so sorry for that. I removed the runat server from tr and td but still the same.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Can you show the code where you bind data to the ListView?  Do you call that in Page_Load?  And do you have it wrapped in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack);` block?

Comment: yes for sure, I will edit my question to have this information

Comment: i added the code, the code is in page load and not in !ispostback

Comment: should I put it in the else of !ispostback?

Comment: I mean the code is directly in the page_load, if you didn't get me tell me please

Comment: you have good idea, it seems that the bind is executed always when the page load, so I need to put something in the !ispostback , right?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes, try wrapping that code in `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //your code here }`

Comment: now when I put the code into the !ispostback, the select is saving its last value, but the input text is still empty :( how could we debug this issue please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Perfect, we're close to a solution!  Try removing one of the ".NamingContainer"s from the second line of code in my answer.

Comment: tried to remove one of them, but still not printing anything on the input

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Since you cannot use breakpoints, put `Response.Write(visitID.NamingContainer.ID.ToString());` in your click event and see what gets written to the web page.

Comment: I got this `53|error|500|Object reference not set to an instance of an object.|`

Comment: bty, I saw the response through firebug, the xhr, then response

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Please come to [this Stack Overflow chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50348/room-for-jadarnel27-and-marco-dinatsoli), and I'll try to help you out more.  It's too hard in comments

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli And I meant for you to use `dropDown.NamingContainer.ID.ToString()`, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind listview in !IsPostback check means when do postback it pageload event fired and it bind dropdown with second time or if its not please share binding code

Comment: I didn't understand what you said, please explain.

Comment: Yes i was aware of that but you see my i m new here and cant able to comment thats why i asked through an answer